# android voice recognition with arrays

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition

I'm trying to make an Android application where

- The user says a word
- This word will be saved into the variable `what_you_say`
- If it matches what I have already stored in the array, the user will say the second phrase

... and so on. The problem is, I made an array and stored in it the words I want the program to compare the word the user says with, but its not working! It keeps giving me false and I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (requestCode ==check && resultCode == RESULT_OK){                       // voice to text 

TextView display2=(TextView)findViewById (R.id.TOF);

String[] words = { "zero", "one", "two" };  
for (int w=0;w<3;w++)
{
    ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
     for(int j=0;j<results.size();j++) {

        String what_you_say = results.get(j);  
         if (what_you_say.equalsIgnoreCase(words[w]))
             display2.setText("true, continue dear");
             //System.out.println("true, continue");
         else
         {
             display2.setText("False, repeat again");
           //System.out.println("False, repeat again");
         }
     }
} 
}//end of for
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}}
```

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? Does nothing display? As a debug methodology, have you tried displaying the actual word that's stored in `what_you_say`?

Comment: Why your for loop begins from `1`?

Comment: like it gives no error,,, but when i run it on the phone,, it just suddenly closes, or the screen becomes black,,, @corsiKa

Comment: @MarounMaroun ,,, my loop begins from one, because i think that arrays in android start their index from 1 not zero.

Comment: @ايمانمحمد indexes start at 0

Answer (score 3):

Index start from **0** and not **1**. You're getting an *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException*.

Change it to:

```
String[] words = { "zero", "one", "two" };  
for (int w=0;w<3;w++)
{
     for(int j=0;j<results.size();j++) {
         what_you_say = results.get(j);  
         if (what_you_say.equalsIgnoreCase(words[w]))
            System.out.println("true, continue");
         else
         {
           System.out.println("False, repeat again");
         }
     }
}
```

Also note, that if you don't ask for `what_you_say` inside the loop, and say it equals to `zero`, your output will be:

> true, continue
>
> False, repeat again
>
> False, repeat again

I think you meant to ask for `what_you_say` on each iteration of the loop. (**code edited**)

Comment: ,,, i edited my code, as you said,, now it just gives me false (the code is on the top)

Comment: `String what_you_say = results.get(0);` You are passing the same `String`. (**0** doesn't change!)

Comment: ,,, ok i put  : String what_you_say = results.get(x);  
  x++;                but now the application suddenly closes, and gives exception!

Comment: i posted it after the editing,, do u want just this ? or did u want the whole .java code?

Comment: `.get(int index)` *Throws IndexOutOfBoundsException - if index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size()).* You should make sure you're not exceeding your `ArrayList` range! See my edit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25633/discussion-between-maroun-maroun-and--)